# Import XML to Excel 2013 - file size limits?

Tags: sql, xml, excel, xml-parsing, xsd

I tried to import a >300MB XML file and it fails though just a few thousand rows!

Is there a maximum processing time or file size?

The same kind of data in 10MB portion works well. Access takes even longer on a 10MB portion and splits it in different tables that don't make sense, so it would be perfect to stay with Excel (with XML redundancy removed the text in the spreadsheet may only be 10% the size).

I am able to set up any (Linux) server solution too of course, even better! Just writing a XQuery script frustrated me since it runs slow and wasn't worth the work just to do this simple conversion that could be automated.

Comment: which excel format are you using? `.xls` has much much lower limits than `.xlsx`, and the .xls limits changed for every edition of excel (e.g. excel 2003 has lower limits than excel 2010).

Comment: xlsx (excel 2013) 
i know of 65536 and 1048576 rows in 2003 and 2007, what are other limits?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Importing XML Crashes Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002663/importing-xml-crashes-excel)

Answer (score 1):

From: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-ca36e2dc-1f09-4620-b726-67c00b05040f  Applies to Excel 2016, Excel 2013.

`Feature                           Maximum limit`

**Worksheet and workbook specifications and limits**

```
Open workbooks                    Limited by available memory and system resources                                          
Worksheet size                    1,048,576 rows by 16,384 columns
Column width                      255 characters
Row height                        409 points
Page breaks                       1,026 horizontal and vertical
Total number of characters  
that a cell can contain           32,767 characters
Characters in a header or footer  255
Sheets in a workbook              Limited by available memory (default is 1 sheet)                                          
Colors in a workbook              16 million colors (32 bit with full access
                                  to 24 bit color spectrum)
Named views in a workbook         Limited by available memory
Unique cell formats/cell styles   64,000
Fill styles                       256
Line weight and styles            256
Unique font types                 1,024 global fonts available for use;
                                  512 per workbook
Number formats in a workbook      Between 200 and 250, depending on the language 
                                  version of Excel that you have installed
Names in a workbook               Limited by available memory
Windows in a workbook             Limited by available memory
Hyperlinks in a worksheet         66,530 hyperlinks
Panes in a window                 4
Linked sheets                     Limited by available memory
Scenarios                         Limited by available memory; a summary report  
                                  shows only the first 251 scenarios
Changing cells in a scenario      32
Adjustable cells in Solver        200
Custom functions                  Limited by available memory
Zoom range                        10 percent to 400 percent
Reports                           Limited by available memory
Sort references                   64 in a single sort; unlimited when using
                                  sequential sorts
Undo levels                       100
Fields in a data form             32
Workbook parameters               255 parameters per workbook
Items displayed in filter
drop-down lists                   10,000
Noncontiguous cells  
that can be selected              2,147,483,648 cells
Maximum limits of memory storage  
and file size for Data Model  
workbooks                         32-bit environment is subject to 2 gigabytes (GB)  
                                  of virtual address space, shared by Excel, the  
                                  workbook, and add-ins that run in the same process.  
                                  A data model’s share of the address space might run  
                                  up to 500 – 700 megabytes (MB), but could be less  
                                  if other data models and add-ins are loaded.
                                  64-bit environment imposes no hard limits on file  
                                  size. Workbook size is limited only by available  
                                  memory and system resources.
```

**Calculation specifications and limits**

```
Number precision                  15 digits
Smallest allowed negative number  -2.2251E-308
Smallest allowed positive number  2.2251E-308
Largest allowed positive number   9.99999999999999E+307
Largest allowed negative number   -9.99999999999999E+307
Largest allowed positive number  
via formula                       1.7976931348623158e+308
Largest allowed negative number  
via formula                       -1.7976931348623158e+308
Length of formula contents        8,192 characters
Internal length of formula        16,384 bytes
Iterations                        32,767
Worksheet arrays                  Limited by available memory
Selected ranges                   2,048
Arguments in a function           255
Nested levels of functions        64
User defined function categories  255
Number of available worksheet  
functions                         341
Size of the operand stack         1,024
Cross-worksheet dependency        64,000 worksheets that can refer to other sheets
Cross-worksheet array formula  
dependency                        Limited by available memory
Area dependency                   Limited by available memory
Area dependency per worksheet     Limited by available memory
Dependency on a single cell       4 billion formulas that can depend on a single cell
Linked cell content length  
from closed workbooks             32,767
Earliest date allowed for  
calculation                       January 1, 1900 (January 1, 1904, if 1904 date  
                                  system is used)
Latest date allowed for  
calculation                       December 31, 9999
Largest amount of time that  
can be entered                    9999:59:59
```

**Charting specifications and limits**

```
Charts linked to a worksheet      Limited by available memory
Worksheets referred to by a chart 255
Data series in one chart          255
Data points in a data series  
for 2-D charts                    Limited by available memory
Data points in a data series  
for 3-D charts                    Limited by available memory
Data points for all data series  
in one chart                      Limited by available memory
```

**PivotTable and PivotChart report specifications and limits**

```
PivotTable reports on a sheet     Limited by available memory
Unique items per field            1,048,576
Row or column fields in a  
PivotTable report                 Limited by available memory
Report filters in a PivotTable  
report                            256 (may be limited by available memory)
Value fields in a PivotTable  
report                            256
Calculated item formulas in a  
PivotTable report                  Limited by available memory
Report filters in a PivotChart  
report                             256 (may be limited by available memory)
Value fields in a PivotChart  
report                             256
Calculated item formulas in a  
PivotChart report                  Limited by available memory
Length of the MDX name for a  
PivotTable item                    32,767
Length for a relational  
PivotTable string                  32,767
Items displayed in filter  
drop-down lists                    10,000
```

**Shared workbook specifications and limits**

```
Users who can open and share a  
shared workbook at the same time    256
Personal views in a shared workbook Limited by available memory
Days that change history is  
maintained                          32,767 (default is 30 days)
Workbooks that can be merged  
at one time                         Limited by available memory
Cells that can be highlighted  
in a shared workbook                32,767
Colors used to identify changes  
made by different users when change  
highlighting is turned on           32 (each user is identified by a separate color;  
                                    changes made by the current user are highlighted  
                                    with navy blue)
Excel tables in a shared workbook   0 (zero)
```